# recursive function error Dev-C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, recursion, dev-c++

I have the following code sequential search run perfectly in Visual C++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int seqSearch(int list[], int length, int item)
{
    int index = length-1;
    if (index < 0)
        return -1;
    if (list[index] == item)
        return (index);
    else seqSearch(list, index, item);
} // end seqSearch

int main () 
{

    int const length = 10;
    int item;
    int list[10] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 40, 80, 45, 99, 0};

    cout << "Please enter the value to be searched: ";
    cin>> item;

    if (seqSearch(list, length, item) == -1) cout << "Item not found." << endl;
    else cout <<"Item found at position: " << seqSearch(list, length, item) << " of list *Note: (first index of list start at 0)" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

But in Dev-C++ it always display result 0, I tried to debug and see index is correct but why it display 0? Why we have this difference between VC++ and Dev-C++?

Comment: A recursive sequential search??

Comment: `else seqSearch(list, index, item);` is not returning anything. Change it to `else return seqSearch(list, index, item);`.

Comment: Most likely not related to your problem, but you might want to look into an other IDE than Dev-C++ for [reasons listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info).

Comment: Vikas is right, just add else return seqSearch(list, index, item); how do I accept your answer?

Comment: Btw, you should not see different behavior. Was that a mistake?

Comment: @LongBodie, I was almost hoping that it was a typo you made while posting here. Are you sure vc++ is working fine with the code you posted. That would really surprise me.

Comment: YES I AM 100% sure VC++ express 2010 work fine, at the very beginning when I start doing this in VC++, I did put "else return seqS..." then for some the reasons it not running, then I changed etc, etc and also remove "return" => It work. Then my friend use Dev-C++ tell me my program always display result 0 when he runs it. ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `int seqSearch` has a code path, `else seqSearch(list, index, item);` that is not returning anything. Changing this to `else return seqSearch(list, index, item);` should solve the problem.

Now digging a little deep.

From [n2960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf) draft:

> § 6.6.3/2
>
> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

So as per the standard it is an undefined behavior.

Digging a little deeper:

- Why is not returning from a non-void function not a compiler error?

Checking all code path to figure out if all of them return is a difficult operation and implementations are not required to check that.

- Why is the code functionally working properly in VC++

This is architecture and [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) dependent. Try following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int fun (int v)
{
    int a = v;
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << fun(5) << std::endl;
}
```

On different compilers the function `fun` returns either `0` or whatever value is passed to it. Basically it can return value of last evaluated expression.

Answer (score 3):

The correct method definition should be

```
int seqSearch(int list[], int length, int item)
{
    int index = length-1;
    if (index < 0)
        return -1;
    if (list[index] == item)
        return (index);
    else return seqSearch(list, index, item);
}
```

You missed out the return statement. Ideally a compiler should warn you but I'm not too familiar with the version that Dev-Cpp uses.

Comment: Still thanks for seeing my question, in VC++ no need to add "return" it still runs well, is that weird?

Comment: No it's implementation specific. To be compliant with the standards, you should have a return statement. Otherwise it may work or it may not work depending on the compiler you use as you have found out.